# Cannot use type assertion on type parameter value

Tags: go, generics

We can't use type assertions on generic typed variables.  This seems like really strange behavior considering it's allowed by `interface{}`, but not by a generic constrained by `interface{}`. Wondering if there are any work arounds?

```golang
// This works
func isInt(x interface{}) bool {
    _, ok := x.(int)
    return ok;
}

// Compile Error
// invalid operation: cannot use type assertion on type parameter 
// value x (variable of type T constrained by interface{})
func isInt2[T interface{}](x T) bool {
    _, ok := x.(int)
    return ok;
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### tl;dr

You can perform a type assertion only on interface values. So you must convert `x` to a valid interface type first, `any` / `interface{}` in this case:

```
func isInt[T any](x T) (ok bool) {

    _, ok = any(x).(int) // convert, then assert
    return
}
```

---

So why does this [fail to compile](https://go.dev/play/p/lrPLafhf5V5)?

```
_, ok = x.(int)   // ... cannot use type assertion on type parameter value ...
```

`x`'s type `T` is a type parameter, not an interface. It is only constrained by an interface. The Go (revised `1.18`) language spec explicitly states [type parameters](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_parameter_declarations) are not allowed in a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

> For an expression `x` of ***interface type, but not a type
> parameter***, and a type `T` ... the notation `x.(T)` is called a type assertion.

---

Also from from the [generics tutorial](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) on why parameter types need to be resolved at compile-time:

> While a type parameter’s constraint typically represents a set of
> types, at compile time the type parameter stands for **a single type** –
> the type provided as a type argument by the calling code. If the type
> argument’s type isn’t allowed by the type parameter’s constraint, the
> code won’t compile.

Comment: This same principle of using a type conversion (to `any`) can be applied to "cannot use a type switch on type parameter value": `switch any(message).(type) {...}`